# Why does tensorflow.function (without jit_compile) speed up forward passes of a Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-xla, xla

[XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla) can be enabled using `model = tf.function(model, jit_compile=True)`. Some model types are faster that way, some are slower. So far, so good.

But why can `model = tf.function(model, jit_compile=None)` speed things up significantly (without TPU) in some cases?

The `jit_compile` [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.13.0/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py#L1519-L1532) state:

> If `None` (default), compiles the function with XLA when running on TPU
> and goes through the regular function execution path when running on
> other devices.

I'm running my tests on two non-TPU (and even non-GPU) machines (with the latest TensorFlow (`2.13.0`) installed).

```py
import timeit

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model_plain = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S()
model_jit_compile_true = tf.function(tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S(), jit_compile=True)
model_jit_compile_false = tf.function(tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S(), jit_compile=False)
model_jit_compile_none = tf.function(tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S(), jit_compile=None)


def run(model):
    model(np.random.random(size=(1, 384, 384, 3)))


# warmup
run(model_plain)
run(model_jit_compile_true)
run(model_jit_compile_false)
run(model_jit_compile_none)

runs = 10
duration_plain = timeit.timeit(lambda: run(model_plain), number=runs) / runs
duration_jit_compile_true = timeit.timeit(lambda: run(model_jit_compile_true), number=runs) / runs
duration_jit_compile_false = timeit.timeit(lambda: run(model_jit_compile_false), number=runs) / runs
duration_jit_compile_none = timeit.timeit(lambda: run(model_jit_compile_none), number=runs) / runs

print(f"{duration_plain=}")
print(f"{duration_jit_compile_true=}")
print(f"{duration_jit_compile_false=}")
print(f"{duration_jit_compile_none=}")
```

```
duration_plain=0.53095479644835
duration_jit_compile_true=1.5860380740836262
duration_jit_compile_false=0.09831228516995907
duration_jit_compile_none=0.09407951850444078
```

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: This should not be meant an argument against bounties, but sadly, yes :-(

Comment: To be clear, that answer has now been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why can model = tf.function(model, jit_compile=None) speed things up significantly (without TPU) in some cases?

The **speedup is mainly due to the graph mode**
[enabled by `tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs), much faster than the eager execution used in `model_plain`.

On top of that, we have **secondary effects of XLA compilation** [with `jit_compile` flag](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla), but they depend very much on the computing architecture. For instance, the numbers would look much different when compiled under the GPU accelerator.

Last but not least, the **benchmarking methodology should be corrected to take into account variation** which is indeed huge for 10 runs and the use-case in question (otherwise, findings will be misleading or even contradictory, e.g. due to high variation `XLA=None` can look faster on average).
For future reference, let's make it clear that **[this profiling pattern from Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function) is inaccurate**

```py
# average runtime on 10 repetitions without variance is inaccurate
print("Eager conv:", timeit.timeit(lambda: conv_layer(image), number=10))
```

The following corrected and extended snippet, executed on Kaggle notebooks with GPU, demonstrates that **improvements come mostly from the graph mode** and that **XLA compilation gives some further speedup**.

```py
import timeit

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model_plain = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S()
model_tffunc = tf.function(tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S(), jit_compile=None)
model_jit_compile_true = tf.function(tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S(), jit_compile=True)
model_jit_compile_false = tf.function(tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S(), jit_compile=False)
model_jit_compile_none = tf.function(tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2S(), jit_compile=None)

x = np.random.random(size=(1, 384, 384, 3))

def run(model):
    model(x)

# warmup
run(model_plain)
run(model_tffunc)
run(model_jit_compile_true)
run(model_jit_compile_false)
run(model_jit_compile_none)

# benchmarking
duration_plain = %timeit -o run(model_plain)
duration_tffunc = %timeit -o run(model_tffunc)
duration_jit_compile_true = %timeit -o run(model_jit_compile_true)
duration_jit_compile_false = %timeit -o run(model_jit_compile_false)
duration_jit_compile_none = %timeit -o run(model_jit_compile_none)

print(f"{str(duration_plain)=}")
print(f"{str(duration_tffunc)=}")
print(f"{str(duration_jit_compile_true)=}")
print(f"{str(duration_jit_compile_false)=}")
print(f"{str(duration_jit_compile_none)=}")
```

Statistically, we have: `duration_plain >   duration_jit_compile_false = duration_jit_compile_none = duration_tffunc > duration_jit_compile_true`, as seen from the output:

```
369 ms ± 3.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
16.1 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
11.6 ms ± 882 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
15.9 ms ± 508 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
15.5 ms ± 450 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
str(duration_plain)='369 ms ± 3.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)'
str(duration_tffunc)='16.1 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)'
str(duration_jit_compile_true)='11.6 ms ± 882 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)'
str(duration_jit_compile_false)='15.9 ms ± 508 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)'
str(duration_jit_compile_none)='15.5 ms ± 450 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)'
```

For a complete example, [see this public notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mskorski/benchmarking-tfgraph).

NOTE: this way of measuring variation is useful but [not fully accurate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).